# Can't do anything with npm after upgrading to 9

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgraded my NPM from 6 to 9 today, and since then, I've been caught in this loop trying to fix the problems that have arisen. When I run *any* npm command, I get this:

```
➜  ~ npm --version       
ERROR: npm v9.2.0 is known not to run on Node.js v10.17.0. You'll need to upgrade
to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This version of
npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 || >=18.0.0`. You
can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

I pulled down and installed the LTS from the Node website, but no matter what I do, I can't change the version of Node being used in my terminal.

```
➜  ~ node -v 
v10.17.0
```

Running `which node` gives me this:

```
/Users/{MY USER NAME}/Library/Caches/fnm_multishells/72546_1673114415649/bin/node
```

NVM isn't working either:

```
➜  ~ nvm use 14
Now using node v14.21.2 (npm v)
➜  ~ node -v
v10.17.0
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You should use either nvm **or** fnm. It looks like fnm is earlier in your path so changing nvm probably won't matter. Maybe update the fnm node version instead? But pick a node version manager and use it.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Perfect! this was the solution, thank you